# Limit in Loading content into WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

i have a problem for load content into my Web View.
The problem is:
i have string like this:

```
String temp=myobj.get(0).getstring; //very long string
 webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("", temp, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "utf-8", "");
```

and when i get the result of

```
myobj.get(0).getstring; //very long string
```

using Log, and set it manually, every thing was OK.
so i really  don't know what is the problem.
do any one know what is the reason  of the problem? 
EDIT: in fact i test a couple of more thing, and i understand it show string but don't show images.

Comment: what is length of your string ?

Comment: it can be different, i fetch it from a site. but the one i tested was:1855 (notice that, set this string manually, show that perfectly).

Comment: You can try trim start and end of string.